# SVN to Git migration in windows using git svn clone

Tags: git, svn, clone

I am trying to migrate code from SVN repository to Git using git svn clone. I want to create a git repository for each module instead of the whole project. We have a slightly non-standard project structure, we have trunk, release branch and branches folder. I am not sure what would be a good place to have the release branch in Git. The current repository structure, the command I used and the result are below. 
I would like maintain the same structure in Git as well.

I have been at this for over a week now and didn't get too far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
https://mydomain/svn/Project/Module/trunk
                                   /release
                                   /branches/branch1
                                   /branches/branch2
                                   /branches/branch3
                                   /branches/closed/closed1
                                   /branches/closed/closed2 
                                   .........

The Module has multiple components.

Module/WebModule
      /WebEar
      /DataModule
      /...

git svn clone https://mydomain/svn/Project/Module Module_Git -T trunk -b branches -b release --no-minimize-url --prefix=svn/ --authors-file=users.txt

git branch -a is displaying the following:

remotes/svn/WebModule
remotes/svn/WebModule@1011
remotes/svn/WebModule@3578
remotes/svn/WebEar
remotes/svn/WebEar@1011
remotes/svn/WebEar@3578
remotes/svn/DataModule
remotes/svn/DataModule@1011
remotes/svn/DataModule@3578
remotes/svn/closed
remotes/svn/branch1
remotes/svn/branch1@1011
remotes/svn/branch2
remotes/svn/branch3
remotes/svn/closed1
remotes/svn/closed2

I am using Git Bash in Windows 7
Git version: 2.19.1
Subversion: 1.9.4
```

I tried svn2git but it fails at git checkout -f master, none of the solutions suggested worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following.

```
git svn init https://mydomain/svn/Project/Module Module_Git -T trunk -b branches --no-minimize-url 

updated .git/config and added the following:

branches = {release}:refs/remotes/*

git svn fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

Options `-b release` gives **a directory** in which `git svn fetch` looks for branches subdirectories. In your case `git svn` gets all subdirectories of `/release/` directory as branches. Which is obviously wrong but there is no simple workaround.

To fetch the `release` directory as a branch you need to move it to a subdirectory. Something like

```
svn mkdir release-dir
svn mv release release-dir
git svn clone https://mydomain/svn/Project\/Module Module_Git -T trunk -b branches -b release-dir --no-minimize-url --prefix=svn/ --authors-file=users.txt
```

If you cannot move the release branch even temporary than my advice is to clone two times, the 1st time using `-T trunk`, the 2nd time using `-T release` (yes, treat the `release` branch as a trunk) and combine the results:

```
git svn clone https://mydomain/svn/Project\/Module Module_Git -T trunk -b branches --no-minimize-url --prefix=svn/ --authors-file=users.txt clone1
git svn clone https://mydomain/svn/Project\/Module Module_Git -T release --no-minimize-url --prefix=svn/ --authors-file=users.txt clone2
cd clone1
git fetch ../clone2 master:release
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I don't want to mess with the current SVN structure. I am trying your alternative.